# Form checkValidity() does not mark failed inputs

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

For some reasons, when I use checkValidity() on a form, the failed inputs are not marked as invalid.

The method is called this way :

```
var result=$("#myForm")[0].checkValidity();
```

When an input is invalid, result is false. But the input is not marked as invalid, there is no visual indication of the error.

I don't know if it is related, but maybe you have to know that the "required" attribute of fields is removed or added dynamically according to user's actions, with code like that :

```
$('input').prop('required',false);
$('input').prop('required',true);
```

You also have to know that I use Bootstrap 4, so the failed inputs should get the "is-invalid" class when they fail. Maybe the manipulation of the "required" property confuses Bootstrap ?

Comment: Can you post the html

Comment: Here is the HTML of an non-working element :

`<input name="theElement" id="theElement" value="" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true" type="text">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The checkValidity-method won't add any classes to the inputs. You'll have to use the CSS-pseudoclass `:invalid` like

```
input:invalid {
    background: red;
}
```

to see it marked invalid.
The addition/removal of "required" should work fine.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not even check it with a basic html form. Indeed, `checkValidity()` has not the same effect as the `submit();`action.

Comment: OK I found a solution for my problem (adding the bootstrap 4 class) : if `checkValidity()`returns false, a little jquery line adds the 'is-invalid' class to invalid inputs : `$("input:invalid").addClass('is-invalid');`

Comment: Cool! I wrote a post about inline-form-validation in case you're interested: https://niorad.github.io/posts/inline-form-validation/

Answer (score 1):

*I know the question has an answer but i put my answer so that it might help someone one day.*

It happened to me too. In my case i changed `button type="click`  to  `button type="submit` inside the form and the html5 validation worked perfectly.